# nodejs Separate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops

I got an array which is a result from webscraping that comes like this:

```
array:
[
  'line1',
  'line2',
  'line3',
  'linen'..
]
```

I have to insert this data to MySQL. The thing is, each 10 lines of the array is one line of MySQL table.

So I have to join line1 to line10 - line11 to line20 and so on..

I tried to create a new array with keys each 10 iterations like this:

```
arrayFinal.push({
    key: counter,
    value: array[i]
});
```

But wasn't the results I expected.

How can achieve this?

- **Update**:

Let's say this is the array (or object idk) that i recieve:

```
array: 
[
    'id',
    'name',
    'age',
    'address',
    'id',
    'name',
    'age',
    'address'
]
```

There's non key that identifies which field is which. I just put the fields like 'id' so you can understand. 
Now, i have to separate this array to insert into mysql. You see a pattern each 4 lines, right?

```
'insert into mysql (id, name, age, address) values ?'
```

Comment: You're confusing `Arrays` and `Objects` here. Show us the exact input/output you desire.

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: @ziad.ali js Array : `['id','name', 'age', ...]`. js Object: `{id: '1', name: 'john', ...}`

Comment: @Logar It comes like this: ['1', 'john', '23', 'street', '2', 'bill', '35', 'street2']

Comment: @ziad.ali thanks, so this is an array. Please update your question and replace  brackets for square brackets :)

Comment: @Logar done! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to separate your `Array` into chunks of `10` and use them like this :

```js
const list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];

//Separate your Array into chunks of 10
let newArray = new Array(Math.ceil(list.length / 10)).fill().map((_,i) => list.slice(i*10,i*10+10));

//Go through your chunks
for(let chunk of newArray){
  //Do whatever you want with them
  console.log('insert into mysql (id, name, age, address, ...) values '+chunk.join(','));
}
```

In the variable `newArray`, there is now an array of 10-length arrays.
For more info, see [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks).

After that, all you need to do is go through this array and create your new `String` using `Array#join`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to transform your input `array` into an `array` of `objects` where each `object` will hold each successive (`id`, `name`, `age` and `address`) combination, you can use a `for loop` with a step equal to `4` to read each 4 elements in a single `object`.

This is how should be your code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i+=4) {
  result.push({
    id: array[i],
    name: array[i + 1],
    age: array[i + 2],
    address: array[i + 3],
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo:

```js
var array = [
  'id',
  'name',
  'age',
  'address',
  'id',
  'name',
  'age',
  'address'
];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i+=4) {
  result.push({
    id: array[i],
    name: array[i + 1],
    age: array[i + 2],
    address: array[i + 3],
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: isn't it `i += 4` instead of `i++` ?

Comment: @Logar hhhhh, yes, my bad I just used to write i++ al the time :D

Answer (score 0):

IF ONLY I guessed what you are looking for correct, below is the code:

```
let arrayFinal = [];
for (var i =0; i < array.length; i+10) {
  end = i + 10;
  end = array.length > end ? end : array.length;
  arrayFinal.push(array.slice(i, end));
}
```